# Installing Magit in Aquamacs

Tags: aquamacs, magit

I have tried with no success to have Magit running under Aquamacs (GNU Emacs 23.4.1). I have followed these steps:

1) I installed Marmelade package manager following [these steps](https://docwhat.org/aquamacs-2-3a-and-marmalade/) (so far so good)

2) M-x package-list-packages (so far so good)

3) I selected and installed Magit from the the list. Here first problems, installation resulted in some errors (unfortunately I haven't copied them). I remember could have been concerning the fact that some files couldn't be written...

4) Reopen M-x package-list-packages. Magit now is at the bottom of the list and results as "Installed"

5) Try M-x magit-status. Result: "Cannot open load file cl-lib".

6) Try to uninstall magit via Marmelade:

```
condition-case: Wrong type argument: stringp, #[(directory &optional recursive

[directory handler recursive delete-by-moving-to-trash directory-files-no-dot-files-regexp directory-file-name expand-file-name find-file-name-handler delete-directory directory-files ...] 7 1863847 (let ((dir (expand-file-name (read-file-name "Delete directory: " default-directory default-directory nil nil)))) (list dir (if (directory-files dir nil directory-files-no-dot-files-regexp) (y-or-n-p (format "Directory `%s' is not empty, really delete? " dir)) nil)))]
```

Answer (score 2):

The version from Marmalade is very old. The recommended way to install Magit is to use the other Elpa package archive: Melpa. See the [updated installation instructions](https://github.com/magit/magit#installation) in the README.md.

Comment: The README.md no longer contains installation instructions, or even a pointer to them. Try https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Installation.html